# google places for iOS empty referrer

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, debugging, google-places-api

I have been working completely fine with google maps sdk and the places api. yesterday my code was running perfectly fine. but woke up this morning, made some modifications then ran into a compiling snowball of issues which seems like an easy fix but have spent a couple hours trying to figure out what is going on. I am trying to develop an iPhone application.

I have gone back, created a "new project" in the developer console
regenerated a new iOS key.
entered the new bundle ID in the info.plist
entered the new api key in the delegate file and within the search parameter of the url.

i am using alamofire and swiftyjson to parse the data

but still get the same issue.

> 2016-01-28 13:15:55.683 Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.11.21919.0
>
> {
>     "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address "myIPAddress", with empty referer",
>     "results" : [
>
> ],
>   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED",
>     "html_attributions" : [
>
> ]
>   }

[image]

```
func downloadRestaurantDetails(completed: DownloadComplete) {
    let URL_Search = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
    let API_iOSKey = "My iOS API Key"

    let urlString = "\(URL_Search)location=\(clLatitude),\(clLongitude)&radius=\(searchRadius)&types=\(searchType)&key=\(API_iOSKey)"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    Alamofire.request(.GET,url).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        if let value  = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value)
            print(json)

            if let results = json["results"].array {
                for result in results {
                    if let placeIDs = result["place_id"].string {
                        self.placeIDArray.append(placeIDs)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        completed()

    }
}
```

Comment: "yesterday my code was running perfectly fine... made some modifications then ran into a compiling snowball of issues" - try restoring your code to yesterday's state. Those issues you are experiencing must have come from the modifications you made.

Comment: I've never known about that feature, thanks for that, but I just looked at how to do so and within Xcode > window > projects > hovered over my project and there are no "snapshots" available. which seems odd since i save regularly

Comment: saving regularly is different from taking snapshots. taking a snapshot saves your project at a specific point in time for cases like this. if you took regular snapshots, you could revert to a previous working version and go from there...

Comment: right now, I suggest looking at a previous Time Machine backup (you use time machine right?). from there you can copy the contents of the problematic file from a previous date and use that to restore your code...

Comment: I'm not making this easy for you to help, sorry :( but i don't use time machine I don't have an external hard drive of any sort. I just don't understand the error i am getting "empty referrer". what could stem from. I have coded back to what it was prior to the modifications. So it has to do with the api keys. I am 99% sure that I have done what i am suppose to in order to get the JSON data........... 1) create a new project in the developer console 2) create iOS API Key 3) make sure bundle identifiers match 4) put iOS key in delegate and within the parameter of the searchURL

Comment: i don't understand also why it gives me an error with my IP address included? nothing within the iOS API Key do i have to give an IP address. that is only for the server key from what i have experienced

Comment: Try using cellular data or switching networks to change your IP...

Comment: just tested on the iPhone over cellular and the IP Address changed. hmm?

Comment: That's meant to happen, just wanted to see if that would affect results

Comment: You say you're using the Google Maps SDK for iOS, but that error looks like a response from the Google Places API **Web Service**.  Are you using the `GMSPlacesClient`? Or are you sending HTTP requests to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/...`?

Comment: haha unfortunately not. I really am at a loss. I've double checked that the bundleID in the general tab and info.plist are the same. that the API key in the delegate and the urlSearch is the same and that it is an iOS key.

Comment: spiv, i updated my question with the source code showing the request. i do have a GMSPlaces client method but it is currently commented out?

Comment: maybe you're not **providing** the referrer (hence "empty referrer"?)

Comment: Dod you add your app's bundle identifier when creating the API key?

Comment: i honestly don't know where i would add a "referrer" i didn't have to manually add anything else on  the last build that was successful. do you mean within the google developer console or within Xcode ?

Comment: i was thinking through Xcode somehow (info.plist maybe?). what about the bundle ID? Did you add your app's bundle identifier when creating the API key?

Comment: The bundle id: I've checked and located 3 places within the target (general, info, and build settings) where it is located. And the info.plist and they are all they same as the one within the google developer console for my project iOS key.

Comment: definitely one of those moments when you want to chuck the computer at the wall. about 9 hours into this problem staring at the screen and trying to locate the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've misconfigured your API key.

First, your issue is with the [Google Places API **Web Service**](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/), which can only be used with [**Server keys**](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key#types_of_api_keys) not iOS keys.  You're calling the web service (`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/place/...`) so iOS keys and bundleID key restrictions aren't going to work here (and are likely to confuse things).

So you need to follow the instructions at https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key, and make a Server Key with "Google Places API Web Service" enabled in the Developers Console (not the same as "Google Places API for iOS").  To be useful on phones you probably don't want to set any IP restrictions (and IP restrictions are the only kind possible for Server keys).  Use that key in your HTTP requests.

Anything else will get REQUEST_DENIED errors.

Comment: Ahhh very helpful thank you i appreciate it tremendously! One question though regarding using a server key, will i actually have to setup a personal "server" that will be used for this sole purpose? i don't have any experience when it comes to this ;/

Comment: You don't have to, it will work fine.  But having a server key in your mobile app isn't great, because it can't usefully have any restrictions set, which makes it relatively easy for someone to extract the key out of your app and use it in their own, using your API quota.  That's one reason why it's better to use the iOS SDKs that support iOS keys, if you can.  If you can't use the iOS SDKs, you should consider adding an easy way to push out updated server keys to your apps so that you can revoke a key that someone is misusing.

Comment: So in essence, although Google Places SDK can be restricted to an iOS App through Bundle id, other Google Maps API key for example the Distance Matrix API, must use a server key and cannot be restricted to iOS app bundle? But why does the Console show an option to restrict it by an app bundle id then? Seems counter intuitive to me and very confusing. The Key restriction idea for google is to prevent quota abuse through misuse of the API Key, which is applicable to both SDK based API and Webservice based APIs.

Answer (score 0):

This error sounds like you have generated a browser key rather than an iOS key. Try generating an iOS key in the Cloud Console and make sure that your bundle ID is whitelisted.

Comment: i added a snapshot of the list and it shows iOS key? idk how it could be a browser key then. How can i whitelist an API key?